# why python json.dumps complains about ascii decoding?

Tags: python, json, codec

I have the following lines in my code

```
outs = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout)
# dJSON contains JSON message with non-ASCII chars
outs.write(json.dumps(dJSON,encoding='utf-8', ensure_ascii=False, indent=indent_val))
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
    outs.write(json.dumps(dJSON,encoding='utf-8', ensure_ascii=False, indent=indent_val))
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
         **kw).encode(obj)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 204, in encode
         return ''.join(chunks)
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 27: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I through that by specifying `encoding='utf-8'` in the `json.dumps` statement, I avoid this type of problem. Why am I still getting the error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My guess is that `dJSON` object does not contain pure unicode but it contains mix of unicode and strings already encoded as `utf-8` e.g. this fails

```
>>> d = {u'name':u'पाइथन'.encode('utf-8')}
>>> json.dumps(d, encoding='utf-8', ensure_ascii=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 204, in encode
    return ''.join(chunks)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

But this works (everything unicode)

```
>>> d = {u'name':u'पाइथन'}
>>> json.dumps(d, encoding='utf-8', ensure_ascii=False)
u'{"name": "\u092a\u093e\u0907\u0925\u0928"}
```

Though this also works (everything string)

```
>>> d = {'name':u'पाइथन'.encode('utf-8')}
>>> json.dumps(d, encoding='utf-8', ensure_ascii=False)
'{"name": "\xe0\xa4\xaa\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\x87\xe0\xa4\xa5\xe0\xa4\xa8"}'
```

Comment: Is there a way of normalizing `dJSON` or using different options in `dumps()` to handle all 3 cases?

Comment: You may hack around it, but I think onus is on the code which is creating dJSON

Answer (score 5):

There is a workaround: pass the `utf8` encoding (not `utf-8`!) to dumps method. In this case it'll force all strings to be decoded to `unicode` first, and you can use a mix of unicode strings and strings already encoded as UTF-8. Why does it work? Because there is such a thing in the source code of `JSONEncoder`:

```
if self.encoding != 'utf-8':
     def _encoder(o, _orig_encoder=_encoder, _encoding=self.encoding):
         if isinstance(o, str):
             o = o.decode(_encoding)
         return _orig_encoder(o)
```

That's what we need, and it'll not work out of the box. But when we change the encoding to `utf8` (that's absolutely the same UTF-8 as `utf-8`), we force this `_encoder` to be defined and everything works just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

as per previous answer, you can work around this with `utf8` vs `utf-8`, but it does not include the "copy paste this" fix.

here's the copy-paste this fix ;P

`your_unicode_result = json.dumps(your_dict, encoding="utf8", ensure_ascii=False)`