# UnicodeDecodeError in json.dump

Tags: python, json, unicode, python-unicode

I have a complex JSON serializable data structure which contains somewhere in it unicode strings and utf-8 byte strings.

When I try to serialize the structure using `ensure_ascii=False`, it fails:

```
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(['\xd0\xb2', u'\xd0\xb2'], ensure_ascii=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 250, in dumps
    sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 210, in encode
    return ''.join(chunks)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
>>>
```

I understand why [this happens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18990554/248296), but is there an easier or built-in way to make it work instead of recursively iterating over the data structure, finding byte strings and decoding them to unicode?

Comment: Why are bytestrings being added to the structure in the first place?

Comment: I don't have control over it. It's a dictionary meant to be updated by API users. I want to make it fool-proof.

Comment: This advice is helpful: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Comment: Yes I know all of this. In an ideal world this would be enough. Still sometimes you just have to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK the reason to serialize to JSON format is to store or to transfer some information. If you specify `ensure_ascii = False`, non-ascii characters are not encoded, which makes no sense at all, because you are looking to encode&serialize your data.

Basically you are trying to get a string with non encoded characters, which is not possible.

From the official docs:

> If ensure_ascii is True (the default), all non-ASCII characters in the output are escaped with \uXXXX sequences, and the result is a str instance consisting of ASCII characters only. If ensure_ascii is False, some chunks written to fp may be unicode instances. This usually happens because the input contains unicode strings or the encoding parameter is used. Unless fp.write() explicitly understands unicode (as in codecs.getwriter()) this is likely to cause an error.

On the other hand, the fact that you are designing an API does not tell that you don't have control over the input. An API is somehow a contract: if some input is given, some output is returned. So you can and should always specify what you are expecting.

In your case, you can check the elements one by one, and convert the bytestrings to unicode. This being said, my proposal is that **you force your users to use unicode** and **dont specify** `ensure_ascii = False`

For me the general rules to understand encoding and avoid problems are these:

1. Strings within your code MUST be unicode.
2. When importing data, DECODE it so that it is unicode. When exporting, ENCODE. This needs that both part agree the encoding they are using, otherwise you just get noise.

Comment: I am intentionally using `ensure_ascii = False` because I save the serialized data to a db and this allows me to save up 66% of the db memory and make it more readable when I access the db directly: `len(json.dumps(u'ф' * 100, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8'))` -> `202`, `len(json.dumps(u'ф' * 100).encode('utf-8'))` -> `602`

Comment: > If you specify ensure_ascii = False, non-ascii characters are not encoded, which makes no sense at all, because you are looking to encode&serialize your data. < I am not sure I understand you. For me it makes perfect sense

Comment: If you don't ensure_ascii, you can have unicode output. If you reencode again as in your example it works but looks cumbersome, since you have a unicode json string and then you encode it to bytes. I don't know then... it seems json.dumps gets confused with mixed unicode and bytes, so you can demand from your user all unicode, or you check your input and convert it all to bytes or unicode.